# Visual Studio update - 'could not load type' error editing tt file

Tags: visual-studio

I updated to VS2019 v16.10 and since then, I get an error every time I type into my tt file (reversePoco).

[image]

From reading what little I can find, it may be related to an extension but I see no way to identify which.  I didn't even have LanguageService installed, so I installed it but no change.

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved on v. 16.11.13 disabling the extension named "Devart T4 Editor", which is apparently shipped with Visual Studio (Menu Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed > Devart T4 Editor > Disable).

You will loss the syntax highlighting on the .TT files, but you can install other working extension like [T4Language](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bricelam.T4Language) (I tried this one) or [t4editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.t4editor).

[(Source)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-update-1610-introduces-could-not-loa/1460034)